# Boot issues Ubuntu 19.10 - power button doesn't work

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I have a dual booted system with Ubuntu 19.10 and Windows 10. Sometimes when i boot Ubuntu the laptop just crashes. When I try to turn it on by pressing the power button, nothing happens. The laptop doesn't even start. It only starts after i plug in the laptop and then Ubuntu works.

When I do the same while keeping the laptop plugged in, there is no issue.

Laptop model: Ailenware M15, RTX 2070 MaxQ
Ubuntu version: 19.10

Comment: Are you sure this is not a hardware problem?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! This sounds very much like a problem with the battery, not Ubuntu!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems clear that this is a hardware problem.

Comment: Are Nvidia drivers installed?

Comment: If the problem was a battery/hardware problem then frenbox would notice it the next time he tried to boot Windows 10.

Comment: Its been almost a month. If i try to boot windows from the grub the computer the laptop doesn’t behave like this ( never has). 
I recently saw in this forum that it might be a nvidia driver  issue and installed it. But the issue was still present. Sometimes it boots and sometime it doesn’t.